# Code-behind files are not generated by Crystal Reports

Tags: .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

Not long ago, we switched to new Crystal Reports version, and I have a problem with auto generating code-behind for a Crystal Reports designer.

It just generates nothing, - empty file. When I right click on the .rpt file and choose Run Custom Tool, it says:

> "Cannot find custom tool
>   'CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.CodeGen.ReportCodeGenerator' on this"

I tried reinstall Crystal Reports, but it does nothing. I have CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.dll in GAC, and even tried to copy it to output folder.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS2010 did not come out with integrated Crystal Reports.  SAP just came out with their RTM for CR for VS2010 (also works with VS2012, VS2013 and VS2015), which does work (I use it currently). You need to download and install this separately from here:

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

You do not state which version of CR you are trying to use, but to my knowledge (and I could be wrong)  there is no commercial version of CR out yet that integrates with VS2010. I would check the SAP CR support forums for clarification on this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using 13.0.0.99.Cortez_CR4VS Crystal Report and VS2010. I tried to install it (file CRforVS_13_0.exe). Size of the file at your link, and mine are the same, but I will download it and install, just for sure. Though, I'm sure that this won't help.

Comment: ArcheG: Well, it at least works for me...  Have you tried creating a new report from scratch to see if that at least works? It would not be the first time I see that sort of thing happen where you have to recreate something in VS in order to get it to work.